# Public does not name a type

Tags: c++

I am facing this issue :

My main.cpp has the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>

#include "Vect.h"


using namespace std;
//color
struct RGBtype
{
    double r,g,b;
};

//function to save image
void samebmp(const char *filename, int w, int h, int dpi, RGBtype *data){
FILE *f;
int k=w*h;
int s=4*k;
int filesize = 54+s;

double factor=39.375;
int m=static_cast<int> (factor);
```

and so forth

Vect.h

```
#ifndef VECT_H
#define VECT_H


class Vect {
    double x,y,z;

    Public:
        Vect ()
            {
            x=0.0;
            y=0.0;
            z=0.0;
            };
        Vect (double,double,double);

        //Getter functions
        double getVectX() {return x;}
        double getVectY() {return y;}
        double getVectZ() {return z;}
};

Vect::Vect(double i,double j,double k)
{
    x=i;
    y=j;
    z=k;
}

#endif
```

When i try to compile the code it throws me this error. I have tried taking help from previous posts however they talk about forward declaration or class dependency. I have neither in my code.

Answer (score 3):

In class Vect.h class Vect should contain

`public:`

instead of

`Public:`

C++ isn't known for it's case insensitivity...